# why left floated block element can't float to the left of his sibling block element before him

Tags: css-float

if there is a inline element before a block element whose float style is left. the block element will float to the left of the inline element horizontally.

if there is a block element before a block element whose float style is left. the floated block element will behind the first block element vertically.

why the floated block element can't float to the the left of the first block element horizontally? is there any rules in the css specification ask browser to follow this behavior? thanks!

sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Can you show the code your trying to make work, or possibly create an example using [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: if you can re-create this using http://jsfiddle.net it'll be much easier for us to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block level elements and inline elements react differently to floated elements around them. Inline elements wrap around floated elements, e.g. text around an image in Word.

A block level element occupies space, so a floated element after the block level element will start floating at the point where the previous element finishes.

Using borders around elements helps to see what's going on:
http://jsfiddle.net/B9FVg/

**HTML**

```
<span>I am inline!</span>
<div class="floating">I'm floating left</div>

<div>I am block!</div>
<div class="floating">I'm floating left</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.floating{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: thanks, Fergal. Recently, i am reading the css specification, there are some rules about float in the specification(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position). these rules doesn't specific the different reaction between inline elements and block elements. so i don't know why inline level element wrap around the floated element, block level elements don't wrap around the floated element.

Comment: Reading the technical specification can be confusing sometimes. Point 8 stands out: "A floating box must be placed as high as possible." The highest point in the second example above is at the bottom of the block level element. The highest point in the first example is where the inline element is. Inline elements don't occupy space the same way as block level elements do. So the floated div slots into the highest point and pushes the text aside. Sorry I don't have the exact technical explanation. I'm happy enough with "because that's how it works" and I move on ;)